# Analytics on web page viewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, analytics

I have an existing ruby on rails webapp. Now I am realizing the need of adding some sort analytics feature for sales and marketing purpose. I have used a javascript api to obtain the viewer's location information. Each time the webpage is viewed by any user , the system shoots a mail to me (admin here). Now I need some additional information along with the viewer's location. We send mails containing the url of our webapp for marketing purpose. Now the viewers of our webapp may come either from normal google search or by clicking the link , sent through mails.

I need this specific information, i.e which link is clicked by the viewer. Is it normal google search result or the link sent through mails.

Please do not suggest me for google analytics. Any other suggestions are welcome. Because it needs to be hard coded in my system.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this gem Ahoy (https://ankane.github.io/ahoy/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [segment.io](http://segment.io/) and then possibly integrate with keen [keen.io](https://keen.io/)

Comment: Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/segment-io-and-ruby

It's all about sending events to segment, and then from segment integrate with other services (like keen.io or google analytics)